# How to create AWS Console Deeplinks behind IAM Identity Center login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sso, aws-iam-identity-center

When managing access to multiple accounts via IAM Identity Center, the AWS Access Portal provides clickable links for each of the available Roles/PermissionSets in those accounts. However, the console always loads to the main page. Is there a way to construct a "deeplink" URL, such that a(n authorized) user who clicks it will:

- be logged in via Identity Center(/SSO)
- be redirected to the desired location within the console

I'm aware that it's possible to [Set Relay State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtopermrelaystate.html) for a given PermissionSet, but this is insufficient as I might want a given user to be redirected to different locations from different links - that is, I want the destination to be encoded in the clicked URL, not in the PermissionSet's metadata. Creating a different PermissionSet for every possible destination is not practical.

[This blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-saml-to-automatically-direct-federated-users-to-a-specific-aws-management-console-page/) seems to describe exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't work for me - following the instructions, I:

- constructed a string `RPID=(url-encoded string of` urn:amazon:webservices`)&RelayState=(url-encoded destination url)`
- URL-encoded that string
- Appended that string (after a `?RelayState=`) to my Access Portal-provided one-click sign-in

However, the resulting URL just signs me in and puts me on the main page, without any redirection.

Sadly, all the links from that article appear to be broken. I also found this page, and tried using it to generate a deeplink - again, no luck, I just got signed in to the main page.

I do note that my sign-in url does not look like the examples - they look like `https://<domain>/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx`, whereas mine looks like `https://<internal-string>.awsapps.com/start/#/saml/custom/AAA/BBB`, where:

- `AAA` is the url-encoded string of `account-number (account-nickname)`
- `BBB` is the url-encoding of some base64-encoded data that refers to the master AWS account, followed by two (underscore-delimited) identifiers I can't place - one of the form `ins-[alphanumerics]`, and the other of the form `p-[alphanumerics]`

Does this mean that my ADFS is differently configured than this feature expects? Is there still a way to achieve what I want?

EDIT: I've been informed by my Network Admin that we use Azure AD internally, not ADFS, which might be the reason for the different URL format.

Comment: I've opened a Support Case regarding this question with AWS. Initial answer just pointed me to [RelayState per PermissionSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtopermrelaystate.html) - I'm continuing to pursue the "redirection per URL" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Customer Support have confirmed that this functionality is not supported. A Feature Request is apparently already open, though I haven't yet been given a public tracking URL - I'll update this answer with it when I receive it.

EDIT: There is no public tracking URL for the Feature Request.